# Proving a functional is continuous before application of Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification

Say $f(a, z) = ||z - \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}||$ where $x_{1}, ..., x_{n}$ are linearly independent vectors from space $X$ and $a = \{a_{1}, ..., a_{n}\} \in R^{n}$.  Ultimately, I want to use Weierstrass to establish that there is an infimum that can be achieved by a vector in the space.  My understanding is this first requires establishing the continuity of $f$, but I'm a bit stuck as to the proper logic.  Here's what I have so far:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(a, z) - f(b, z) &= ||z - \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}|| - ||z - \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}x_{i}|| \\
&\leq ||(z - \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}) - (z - \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}x_{i})|| \\
&= ||\sum_{i=1}^{n}(b_{i} - a_{i})x_{i}|| \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i} - b_{i}|\cdot||x_{i}||
\end{aligned}
$$

That's as far as I got myself, but then I came across some work which suggested the following:

Since $a$ and $b$ in the above are arbitrary,
$$
|f(a, z) - f(b, z)| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i} - b_{i}|\cdot||x_{i}||
$$
and thus, given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta = (\epsilon / \sum_{i}||x_{i}||)$ such that $\forall b$, if
$$
||a - b||_{1} < \delta
$$
then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i} - b_{i}|\cdot||x_{i}|| < \delta\sum_{i=1}^{n}||x_{i}|| = \epsilon
$$

What's the intuition behind the choice of $\delta = (\epsilon / \sum_{i}||x_{i}||)$?  Is it just that the above formula is effectively
$$
||a - b||_{1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}||x_{i}|| < \delta\sum_{i=1}^{n}||x_{i}|| = \epsilon
$$

Similarly how does this actually prove continuity here?  I think I'm getting mixed up by existence of arbitrary norm as well as 1-norm.  Is it that we've established that if
$$
||a - b||_{1} < \delta
$$
then,
$$
||(z - \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}) - (z - \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}x_{i})|| < \epsilon
$$

Comment: Simply put, $f$ is a positive function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $f$ is restricted to a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then it attains its minimum by continuity.  Continuity of $f$ follows from the continuity of the norm (which in turn follows from the symmetry axiom and triangle inequality) together with the continuity of $a\mapsto a\cdot x$ which is easy to show.

Comment: @Medo That makes sense, I think I'm just a bit mixed up about this specific example.  Specifically I'm missing something regarding the extrapolation from $\delta$ to $\epsilon$ in the above.  The above seems to assume equivalence of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i} - b_{i}|\cdot||x_{i}||$ and $||a-b||_{1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}||x_{i}||$, no?  Or can we assume the former is smaller than the latter via some inequality I'm missing?

Comment: I suppose given $|a_{i}-b_{i}|$ and $||x_{i}||$ are non-negative we can assume the product of sums is greater than or equal to the sum of products and that's the missing step?

Comment: For the implication you are asking about, you can assume that $\|x_{i}\|\leq 1$ for all $i$. If not then divide both sides by $\max_{1\leq i \leq n}{\|x_{i}\|}$.